# SQL Server Management Studio: missing "Security" page

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms

I have SQL Server in Docker. I need to access the "Security" page in properties, but it did not appear. What could the reason for that be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I guess, it's just because SQL Server in Docker works on Linux, and there is only one option: SQL Auth and that's why "Security" page is missing.

Comment: Thanks for circling back and putting the answer down for future users!